# real number of cores in r server on hdinsight Azure

Tags: windows, machine-learning, bigdata, azure-hdinsight, rstudio-server

I have a question please, regarding the r HDinsight server on Azure, I configured a clan with 4 nodes, the main one with 32 cores.
Here is the screenshot of the configuration.
[image: screenshot of the configuration]

But when I connect with sshuser at the R studio interface, and I use the command

```
 detectCores (all.tests = FALSE, logical = TRUE)
```

he returns to me only 4 cores? !
[image]
any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to R Studio it's running on the cluster's edge node. Therefore, detectCores will recognize the 4 cores of the edge node, not the 32 cores of the worker nodes.

To see the worker node cores, you can set a Spark compute context and use rxExec with detectCores.

Comment: Thank you, Please, how can I do to use the 32 cores?